# I can't send value between 2 project winform

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have 2 project on solutions.

- Project 1: Winform with vb
- Project 2: Winform with C#

I need connect 2 project and send value between 2 project.

Comment: You mean project 1 will call a function in project 2 with some data that are collected in project 1?

Comment: You need to pass the instance of the class. See my answer at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on interprocess communication. One common way to implement on Windows is to use named pipes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication